# How to disable ContextMenu vanishing on RightMouseUp?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, mouseevent

How do I disable ContextMenu vanishing on RightMouseUp ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [StayOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.staysopen.aspx) property, it should keep it open until you close it from the code.

Edit:

If you need to keep it opened when you click on the items you can use [StaysOpenOnClik](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.staysopenonclick%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property on the MenuItem object.

Comment: @Erez, you need to keep the ContextMenu opened when you right click on an item ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I need.
As a matter of fact I need it to stay open and to open on it another context menu but this is other problem.
First I want it not to be closed.